# Insert into MySQL table from oracle using dblink

Tags: mysql, oracle, dblink

I do have DBLINK between oracle database instance and mysql database .
I connected in oracle database using plSQL developer tool. 
i created synonym for mysql table.

```
CREATE SYNONYM "ATL2_SSO_USER_APPL" FOR "atl_sso"."ATL_SSO_USER_APPL"@"ATUL_SSO.ATUL.CO.IN";
```

What steps should i follow to do so?

```
Select * from ATL2_SSO_USER_APPL
```

working fine. But i am not able to insert into that table.
When i tried

```
Insert into ATL2_SSO_USER_APPL
```

it throws error

> unknown column 'atl_sso.atl_SSO_USER_APPL.appl_id' in 'where clause'
>   ora-02063 : preceding 2 lines from atl_sso.

Comment: There's no `WHERE` clause in your `INSERT` query. It's also missing values to insert. That can't be the whole query.

Comment: Please provide complete insert query and destination mysql table column details

Comment: I think it may not have any issue . Issue might be with spelling. 
INSERT INTO atl2_sso_USER_APPL (user_name,appl_id,created_by,last_updated_by)
VALUES (2,2,1,1);
working proper.